# System idle process

Tags: macos, process, cpu-usage

When the cpu isn't doing anything, it runs the idle process. I heard that this process looks for programs that are waiting in the queue so that the cpu can run them. Is that all it does? I am also interested in knowing the file name of the system idle process in the various OSes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When the cpu isn't doing anything, it
>   runs the idle process.

Yes.  All multitasking OSes have one.  The process does nothing at all.  It just is a placeholder when nothing else is running.  Having a do-nothing process is simpler than having a special case when the processor is idle.  It is always the lowest priority, so is always replaced by something that can do real work.

> I heard that this process looks for
>   programs that are waiting in the queue
>   so that the cpu can run them. Is that
>   all it does?

It doesn't do this.  The OS scheduler does this.  The scheduler is part of the kernel (almost always) and is not a process.